# dlux and apidocs not found in OpenDayLight startup archetype

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

Based on the [doc](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html), I downloaded & installed OpenDaylight `opendaylight-startup-archetype 1.1.0`, then I wanted to install dlux-core, dluxapps and mdsal-apidocs to help navigating ODL interface via a browser. However, the karaf CLI said that those features weren't present in the repository.

How can I install DLUX and apidocs? Here's [a list of available features](http://pasted.co/441273bf).

Step to reproduce:

```
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
mvn clean install
./karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf
feature:list | grep dlux => Not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doc explorer feature is called odl-mdsal-apidocs, not mdsal-apidocs.

The dlux and dluxapps feature repos aren't included by the archetype - it's just a starting point - you can add whatever other feature you want. That said, the dlux and dluxapps projects are no longer actively maintained and thus were archived a few months ago. However you can still download and get them to build yourself. If you're interested in rebooting them upstream, contributions are always welcome.

Comment: Please take a look at the list of features above, `odl-mdsal-apidocs` wasn't listed. Also, if dlux projects are inactive, is there any substitute UI for the current version?

Comment: Not upstream currently - ODL needs contributors to maintain all this functionality...